# Drobo FS vs Lime Technology unRAID vs FreeNAS

Tags: nas, freenas, drobo

I already decided to by a Drobo FS until I just found these two tests:

- http://www.digitalversus.com/data-robotics-drobo-fs-p889_9543_487.html
- http://www.digitalversus.com/lime-technology-unraid-p889_8992_473.html

The two cons agains drobo for me:

- loudness
- price

What disadvantages has the unraid stuff against the drobo fs? Has it also got that ease of use like swapping drives on the go, simply extend capacity by plugging in new drives, notify me of drive errors, disk failure protection, dynamic space of "partitions", better/worse effective capacity, etc. Which is more secure? Am I able to simply replace a bad drive with a new one on unraid? What happens if my pc fails? Lets say the cpu overheats.

Since I have a complete pc which is going to be replaced, I only have to pay the software to use unraid.

I am going to use my nas for:

- music library (how well does it integrate with iTunes? )
- picture library
- movie library
- development (i need to be able to be to use time machine)

I am going to use this nas with a MacBook pro.

My current disks:

- 2x 500Gb
- 1x 1.5Tb
- 1x 2Tb

On a drobo fs I would have 2.26 Tb of space. What would it be on unraid?

Is [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/) also an alternative?

Comment: For what it's worth, I find my Drobo to be very quiet.

Answer (score 2):

For your home network, any of those is "fast enough".  I promise you won't notice the difference... really.

Comparative performance only becomes a concern if you're trying to use it for virtual machine storage (e.g. iSCSI) or if you're creating a share for a larger workgroup... say at least 25 users or more, where you have enough that several people will frequently hit it for large transfers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Freenas you won't get the ability to just pop in drives of different sizes.  With Unraid you will.  Unraid is slower than a real RAID5 array.  To calculate the usable space you will get with any set of drives look at the UnRAID Capacity Calculator at http://unraid.category5.tv   The FAQ at http://lime-technology.com/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ#What_are_the_advantages_of_unRAID_over_similar_products.3F  May also be of some help to you.  I think if I didn't need speed and had your collection of drives I'd go Unraid for sure.  If I had say 3+ 1TB drives I'd use FreeNas with a real SOFTWARE Raid5.  If I wasn't as poor as I am I'd buy a real Syncology NAS and not cobble something together..:)   I hope this has been some help to you.  -  Joe

Comment: ok... but the usability of a raid 5 is not as good as a drobo or an unraid. as long as i am able to watch full hd movie its ok.

Answer (score -2):

I use FreeNAS in my office and large files uncorrupted.
if you can, FreeNAS is the best sulução to save:

```
-music library (how well it integrates with iTunes?)
-picture library
-Film Library
-development
```

You buy 3 x 2TB RAID5 and intall and you have storage for your life